# What is causing certain data to display weird in this d3 chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

What is causing the grey bars in this chart? Only happens in weird certain places and I can't figure it out.

http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/f9cb47fa9e32ce34011a

Answer (score 1):

It happens on a couple days (12/18/13 and 3/25/14) when the open and close values are the same, i.e. the price didn't go up or down. So the volume bar keeps the default CSS color:

```
path.volume {
    fill: #AAAAAA;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

rather than either the up or down classes:

```
path.volume.up {
    fill: #00AA00;
}

path.volume.down {
    fill: #FF0000;
}
```

It's actually not entirely clear from the example why any of the bars are not grey, but it must take on the up or down class via a function in the minified techan javascript file:

```
var volume = techan.plot.volume()
        .accessor(techan.accessor.ohlc())   // For volume bar highlighting
        .xScale(x)
        .yScale(y);
```

probably somewhere near this function in the minified file:

```
e.appendUpDownEqual(c.selection,i.accessor,"ohlc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are there on purpose, it's where the volume trading was equal (ie the open the close prices are the same). The first gray bar is on Dec. 13th:

```
18-Dec-13,55.57,55.89,53.75,55.57,76003479
```